# Imports failing in React 16 tests with enzyme and jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a lot of tests that were working properly before upgrading to React 16, along with the respective upgrades to enzime and jest. I followed [the instructions](https://medium.com/@mateuszsokola/configuring-react-16-jest-enzyme-typescript-7122e1a1e6e8) and added these two files to the jest configs in my package.json

```
"jest": {
  "globals": {
    "rootLevel": "/portal"
  },
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "components": "<rootDir>/../components",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$": "<rootDir>/_tests/__mocks/fileMock.js"
  },
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/_tests/__config/shim.js",
    "<rootDir>/_tests/__config/enzyme-setup.js"
  ]
}
```

But I'm still not seeing my tests running properly. Most of my tests thrown an error identical to this:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Check the render method of `WrapperComponent`.
at invariant (node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42:15)
...
at mount (node_modules/enzyme/build/mount.js:19:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (_tests/MyTest.test.js:39:35)
```

All that triggered that was this line:

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent {...props} />)
```

As far as I could tell, `mount` still works the same in enzyme 3. All my tests that involve rendering something are failing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that a `$` was missing in the module name mapper:

```
"components$": "<rootDir>/../components",
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to "components" in the URL you posted.  Otherwise, this file should be auto-generated with create-react-app.